# Client Side calls to Page Methods/WebMethod or Update Panel SharePoint 2010

Tags: jquery, ajax, sharepoint, webmethod

I am trying to figure out the best practice methodology for being able to update the client in my web application. I am working on a User Administration screen and the data is very dynamic hence the need to update the client often. I am confused as to what is the prefered or best approach though. I finally got WebMethods working in my SharePoint environment and came across this video [What not to do in ASP.NET](http://vimeo.com/68390507). Which says don't use Page Methods anymore. However I have also come across [**this**](http://encosia.com/why-aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-dangerous/) which states why using the Update panel is dangerous. I like the idea of using Jquery and Ajax and putting the [WebMethod] in my code behind. I know it has to be static, but that is ok for me.

```
   [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string JsonMSG()
    {
            string MSG = "Hey I'm not JSON";

            return MSG;

    }
```

Really confusing as to what is correct or prefered way. I mean, I guess I could create a WCF service, but is that old now too. Should I use ASP.NET Web API? SignalR? Also very confused as to which framework using which file extension .svc and .asmx. I wish MS would just stick to standard. If anything I think RestFul is the way I want to go.

Comment: Bueller Bueller anyone? http://youtu.be/f4zyjLyBp64

Answer (score 0):

That's my post about UpdatePanels that you linked to. So, you know I've been a fan of using the static `[WebMethod]` approach.

I think that approach still is a great improvement over an UpdatePanel when it comes to efficiency, but if ASP.NET Web API is also a choice then you should absolutely go with that. Web API is hands-down more flexible and powerful, without sacrificing very much simplicity at all.